# react js getting error when i use serverside datatable

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am working on react js server side datatable, for that i have used this library `https://github.com/kenforthewin/react-redux-datatable`, when i run the program it gives me this error

```
./src/Table.js
  Line 9:  'persistCombineReducers' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 9:  'config' is not defined                  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Can anyone please help me why i am getting that error ? I have added my whole code here

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './App.css';
import reducers from './reducers'
import { dataTableReducer } from './redux-remote-datatable';
import { DataTableRedux as DataTable } from './redux-remote-datatable';

const appReducer = persistCombineReducers(config, {
  dataTableReducer,
});



class TableData extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: [],
      CustomComponent: null
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DataTable
        fields={{ "id": "id","first_name": "first_name","last_name": "last_name"}}
        ajax="https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2"
        idField="id" />
    )
  }
}
export default TableData;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `persistCombineReducers` but I think you forgot to import it or define it, see your code carefully,

if you are using `redux-persist` package then look the below code,

```
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
...
export default {
  auth: persistReducer(config, combineReducers({
    token,
    error,
  })),
}
```

this way you can use the functionality, please go through this [link: redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

Comment: It is a compilation error, you forgot to import/define `persistCombineReducers`, please go through the code carefully and make sure the variable/function is in the scope where it is used.